# Florida driving license in the UK

Tags: driving-licenses

I have moved back to the UK after living in the USA, my Florida license is valid for a year. If I leave the UK and re enter before the 12 months is up will my license be valid for another year ??

Comment: 1) I don't think it works like that, you would have to get a UK license; 2) I think this belongs in expats-SE rather than Travel

Comment: Thank you so much for the input, I didn't think I could leave and re enter but wanted to make sure.

Comment: It's a pretty well-known problem on expats-SE; without being resident in the US, it's impossible in most states to renew a US driving license. You may need to get a new one in the UK, unfortunately. I was there for 5 years and just never bothered. Look into swapping programs, if they exist its much easier than re-testing!

Answer (score 6):

No. See https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence.

You may use your Florida license for up to one year after becoming a resident.  Leaving the UK and reentering does not change the date on which you became a resident.